# Unicode in NetBeans 6.7.1

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, utf-8, georgian

When I type any text on Georgian language. NetBeans shows it like question marks. I'm using Windows7(georgian keyboard).

I've also tried in Eclipse, but there is no such problem (everything works fine). Then I've tried to open my Eclipse project folder in NetBeans with some html files and the question marks appeared again. (The html files where saved as utf-8 without BOM).

Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem fixed! I was using consolas as editor font. I've changed it to sylfaen(which is known to support georgian) and the Georgian characters begun to appear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see question marks in text where special characters should be it generally means that the font you are currently using doesn't support these characters. This is different from seeing small boxes, which usually indicates that there is a problem with text encoding. This is a problem across many different programs, and can usually be solved by switching fonts. The OP solved the problem by using Sylfaen. Arial Unicode MS is generally a good choice for most languages.